# Trade settlement date in phpmysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to implement a settlement date algorithm to check for local public holidays in my region for a small trading application built in php/mysql. I have all local public holiday dates stored neatly in my db and then i output using a variable.

The application should check the current date and then add three working days (Minus weekends) as the settlement cycle in my country follows a t+3 settlement rule for all trades. This requires that if the settlement should fall on a public holiday or weekend, the application should compare the dates in the db table and then set a new working day as the settlement date.

can someone please help me with what i may be missing? Please find the code below:

```
<?php 
$rsd = date ( 'Ymd' , strtotime ( '3 weekdays' ) ); 
$phd = $row_public_holidays['date'];

if ($rsd == $phd) {
echo date ( 'Ymd' , strtotime ( '4 weekdays' ) );
} else {
echo date ( 'Ymd' , strtotime ( '3 weekdays' ) );
}
?>
```

Comment: If you need a two digits day format, you should use 'd' instead of 'j' in your date format - 'Ymd' instead of 'Ymj'

Comment: Thanks for your input Anton. Does this mean that the code computes if the formats are adjusted? I also have a concern that the code is not computing and pulling the desired result. If this is true that the code computes then i should mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the output of `date` to have 8 digits, you can update the format string from `Ymj` to `Ymd`. Changing the last character from `j` to `d` moves from showing:

> Day of the month without leading zeros

to:

> Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros

As per the documentation for `date` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

#### Putting this together

The call to `strtotime` performs the calculation and returns an integer representing the seconds since epoch in the determined (or provided) timezone (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). The call to `date` is simply to format that integer into a string based on the provided format (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

So:

```
$time = strtotime('4 weekdays');
var_dump($time);

$date1 = date('Ymj', $time);
var_dump($date1);

$date2 = date('Ymd', $time);
var_dump($date2);
```

outputs:

```
int(1533600000)
string(7) "2018087"
string(8) "20180807"
```

In this example, the calls to `date` don't change the value of `$time`.

Comment: thanks for your input as well msbit. Does this mean that the code computes if the formats are adjusted? I also have a concern that the code is not computing and pulling the desired result. If this is true that the code computes then i should mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @amldev I've added some information to the answer to cover what I understand you're asking here.

Comment: Thanks @msbit. I have gotten that bit to work but that is just one part of the puzzle. Another concern I have is if the code will compute because it is supposed to compare dates in the db and then apply the difference. I want to know if this code will compute. Let me know if you need more details to further illuminate my question.

Comment: @amldev Unfortunately I don't think I understand exactly what you are trying to achieve; you may need to edit the question, maybe adding more code/context.